# How return a yaml file as result of an asp.net core ViewComponent

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent, fileresult

I want to create an asp.net core ViewComponent that dynamically return a yaml file based on some criteria:
For example

```
namespace MyNameSpace {

[ViewComponent(Name = nameof(MyViewComponent))]
public class MyViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(object input)
    {
        string yamlDocument = GetYamlDocumentByInput(input);
        //how to proceed here so that my yamlDocument is returned with the right content type?
        return View(..., yamlDocument);
    }
}}
```

Comment: Hi @rickky, what do you mean for `return a yaml file`? Do you want to download it or just display it with right content type? More details would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Rena, I mean download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could search the view component class，and there‘s no method can return a file as result.
[image: ViewComponent]

you'd better add an action in your controller to download file,and you could send a request to this action after your view has been rendered  mannully or automaticlly.
and there's the  codes in the action:

```
public FileResult DownLoad(Person  person)
       
        {
            
            var serializer = new SerializerBuilder()
                                    .WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
                                    .Build();
            var yaml = serializer.Serialize(person);            
            byte[] yamlArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yaml);
            return File(yamlArray, "application/x-yml");
         }
```

Result:
[image: Result]